# How to reset canonical URLs / fix redirect loop

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls

Couldn't find anything in the related questions, so here goes:

I have a post which, when viewed on the site, is returning a redirect loop. The error page is showing an address for the post that originated when the post was added to a category that was subsequently deleted.

[www.macrowikinomics.com/innovation-communities/business-economics/will-facebook-be-your-crm-provider](http://www.macrowikinomics.com/innovation-communities/business-economics/will-facebook-be-your-crm-provider) is the correct address, but it keeps redirecting to www.macrowikinomics.com/innovation-communities/guest-authors/will-facebook-be-your-crm-provider/. Guest-authors was the old category obviously.

My thought was it might be the automatic canonical URL redirect feature. Despite adding the disable canonical url function (src = Mark Jaquith) it continues to redirect to this old address. Cleared the cache and cookies and still it goes. Tried it in another browser and I continue to get the error. There is also no cache plugin running on the site.

Could it be something in the pretty permalinks? They're using the format /%category%/%postname%/

Many thanks for any thoughts you can provide.

Comment: By any chance, do you have the Redirection plugin or a similar one installed? I know a feature of that is to automatically create redirects of pages if you change the name/url. Sometimes I get infinite loops if I change a page's name or url and then change it back without remembering to remove the redirect from the plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you use a plugin called [Redirection?](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) It has a setting that will automatically create redirects when a post permalink is changed, and if the post is renamed and then changed back to the original name, you get a loop. And if a category is removed, WP will reassign a post to the default category and that may be part of it, too.

Also, check .htaccess for any hardcoded 301 redirects.

Comment: Thank you very much! Forgot that redirection was even installed.

Comment: I can confirm this settings just kills the page if you change the slug back and forth to the same values ... Thanx songdogtech for this hint !